# Why does $\lim_{z \to c} f(z)(z-c)=0$ imply that $\int\limits_{\partial B}f(\zeta)d\zeta=0 $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am using the book Theory of Complex Functions by Remmert.
In chapter 7 there is a corollary that says for a function $f:D\to\mathbb{C}$, $D$ domain:
If $f$ is bounded around $z$, then  $\int\limits_{\partial B}f(\zeta)d\zeta=0 $.
Where $B=B_{r}(c)$ and $\overline B\subset D$.

Then there is some sort of remark that says:
The integral already vanishes if f satisfies

$\lim_{z \to c} f(z)(z-c)=0$

I don't understand why this is true. A few pages later he talks about Riemann's Theorem about removable singularities. There he states the condition $\lim_{z \to c} f(z)(z-c)=0$ but uses things in the proof that are not "available" to me yet. I think it is possible to proof his remark using Goursat's, Morera's and Cauchy's Integral Theorem but Morera's Theorem is also not at my disposal yet.Furthermore there is version of Goursat's Theorem that makes weaker assumptions. This version is I think necessary to proof the claim.
What am I missing? How do you proof the claim only using the things that have been proven so far?
Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: it says that if $f(z)$ is holomorphic/analytic on $0 < |z| < a$ and $\lim_{z \to 0} f(z) z = 0$ then for $0 < r < a $ : $\ \int_{|z| = r} f(z) dz = \lim_{ \epsilon \to 0} \int_{|z| = \epsilon} f(z) dz = 0$ (since $|\int_{|z| = \epsilon} f(z) dz| < \int_{|z| = \epsilon} |f(z)| d|z| = \epsilon \max_{|z| = \epsilon} |f(z)| = \max_{|z| = \epsilon} |z f(z)|$)

Comment: do you mean the corollary or the remark?

Comment: And when writing $\int_{|z| = r} f(z) dz = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|z| = \epsilon} f(z) dz$ I'm using the Cauchy integral theorem

Comment: And for proving $f(z)$ is holomorphic/analytic at $z = 0$, I prefer to prove that $z=0$ is a pole or an essential singularity, and that in both case it would be contradicting $\lim_{ z \to 0} z f(z)  =0$  (the essential singularity part requiring the Liouville theorem : the non-existence of a bounded entire function)

Comment: Unfortunately Liouville has not been proven yet.

Comment: That has also not been proven. Only Goursat with very strict assumptions.

Comment: Morera or Liouville don't need Riemann's theorem on removable singularities, so no problem for proving it from Morera or Liouville

Comment: would you say without those theorems it is rather diffucult to show this? I am a bit puzzeled since up to now proofs that were left to the reader have mostly been rather short.

Comment: So now your question is : what are all the ways for proving Riemann's theorem on removable singularities  :) ? I don't know, make some researches you'll find easily what are the most common proofs.

Comment: oh okay... I think there has been a misunderstanding. I only want to know how to proof the implication as stated in the heading without using Morera's Theorem or Liouville, because they have not been proven yet.

Comment: If i am not mistaken your argument required Liouville. I will have a look at it again!

Comment: 1st comment (answering your tittle question), not 4th one (for proving Riemann's theorem on removable singularities)